# How can I make a condition opposite in MySQL?

Tags: php, mysql, sql

I have this query:

```
$db
->prepare("UPDATE users 
            SET reputation = reputation + 
                             CASE
                               WHEN id = ? THEN 2
                               WHEN id = ? AND ? THEN 15
                             END
            WHERE id IN (?, ?); ")
->execute(array($author_ques_id, $author_ans_id, $bool, $author_ans_id, $author_ques_id));
```

Please focus on this condition:

```
WHEN id = ? AND ? THEN 15
//              ^ this is containing a boolean value
```

And I want to opposite the value of that condition. I mean I want to run that condition when `$bool` is `false` and don't run it when it is `true`.

I can do that before passing by php:

```
$bool = !$bool;
```

But I want to know can I do that in the query by MySQL?

Comment: have you tried to do the same here? like `->execute(array(..., !$bool, $author_ans_id, ...));`

Comment: @Jeff Yes that's possible .. But I want to know is that possible to I do that by MySQL?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use `NOT`:

```
... AND NOT ? THEN 15
```

Comment: Oh really?! That's why `NOT` is for ?! Sweet `:-)` +1

Comment: Also if you're looking for the equivalent of `!=` in direct comparisons (typically numbers), the standard SQL operator is `<>` ('less than or more than', I guess)

Answer (score 1):

Maybe you mean
... `AND ? IS FALSE`  or
... `AND ? IS NOT TRUE`

http://code.openark.org/blog/mysql/syntax-of-the-day-is-true-and-is-false